# NPE in HandledContributionItem.canExecuteItem

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, e4

I have this little editor with a toolbar contributed by the *plugin.xml*:

```java
public class MyEditor extends EditorPart {

    public static final String ID = "org.acme.project.MyEditor";

    @Override
    public void init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input) throws PartInitException {
        setSite(site);
        setInput(input);
    }

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        final ToolBarManager localToolBarmanager = new ToolBarManager();
        final IMenuService menuService = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IMenuService.class);
        menuService.populateContributionManager(localToolBarmanager, "toolbar:org.acme.menu");
        localToolBarmanager.createControl(parent);

    }
}
```

And of course, my *plugin.xml* has a contribution:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution allPopups="false" locationURI="toolbar:org.acme.menu">
        <command commandId="org.eclipse.ui.file.saveAll" style="push" />
    </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

The editor opens, the toolbar gets contributed, everything is fine. When I close the workbench part that was active when I open the editor, I get the following exception:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt 4 2 2017-10-30 15:12:53.110
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.canExecuteItem(HandledContributionItem.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem$4.run(AbstractContributionItem.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.updateItemEnablement(AbstractContributionItem.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolItemUpdater.updateContributionItems(ToolItemUpdater.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolBarManagerRenderer.subscribeTopicUpdateToolbarEnablement(ToolBarManagerRenderer.java:295)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.di.UIEventObjectSupplier$UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventObjectSupplier.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4211)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3827)
```

And it's really only the one part that had focus. I can close other parts just fine. This exception leads to the handlers in the toolbar being broken and the toolbar not working anymore.

I found some bugs with that exception: [Bug 388516](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388516) & [Bug 394500](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=394500)

But these were supposedly fixed in 4.2 (and we are using 4.6). Other then that, I can't find anything which might result in weird error messages like that.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix our toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's one of the stupider E4 bugs. Probably Top 3 for us.

`WorkbenchMenuService.populateContributionManager(ContributionManager, String)` takes the currently active workbench part to register the menu for. Since toolbars are usually created in `IWorkbenchPart.createPartControl(Composite)`, that means the new part was not yet fully created, and so is **not** yet the active part.

**So toolbars do not work anymore for all views and editors!!!**

I found a workaround (that is really ugly, but what are you going to do?) to fix this massive E4 bug. The call to `populateContributionManager` must be replaced with the following lines:

```
    final MPart part = getSite().getService(MPart.class);
    String menuLocation = "toolbar:org.acme.menu";

    if (menuService instanceof WorkbenchMenuService) {
        ((WorkbenchMenuService) menuService).populateContributionManager(part, manager, menuLocation);
    } else if (menuService instanceof SlaveMenuService) {
        ((SlaveMenuService) menuService).populateContributionManager(part, manager, menuLocation);
    } else
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Do not know how to handle " + menuService); //$NON-NLS-1$
```